# Add _ to multiple elements in R

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have hundreds of variable names that look like this:

```
c("B02001001","B02001002","B23020003","B19057001")
```

But I need them to look like this:

```
"B02001_001","B02001_002","B23020_003","B19057_001"
```

I'm assuming there's an easy way to do this...stringr perhaps?  Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: the problem is underspecified, but if the first part is fixed, `gsub("2001", "2001_", c("B02001001","B02001002","B02001003","B02001004"))` would do the trick.

Comment: thanks! I didn't put that up there correctly.  What if the the numbers are all different after the B?

Comment: Are they all 9 characters?  `paste(substr(x, 1, 6), substr(x, 7, 9), sep = "_")`

Comment: consider editing the question with the exact pattern of the generic string, and where the _ should go

Comment: thanks! that's it. @Richard Scriven.

Comment: And my apologies @baptiste - I'm not all that familiar with the coding conventions of R as of yet or how to ask the questions appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can do

```
x <- c("B02001001","B02001002","B23020003","B19057001")

paste(substr(x, 1L, 6L), substr(x, 7L, 1e5L), sep = "_")
# [1] "B02001_001" "B02001_002" "B23020_003" "B19057_001"
```

`1e5L` is only there as a safety precaution in case some strings are longer than 9 characters.  If you know they are all 9 just replace that with `9L`.  You could also use `substring()` as the second call and not worry about that.

```
paste(substr(x, 1L, 6L), substring(x, 7L), sep = "_")
# [1] "B02001_001" "B02001_002" "B23020_003" "B19057_001"
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sub` with capture groups.  We capture the first group as 6 characters (`(.{6})`) followed by the characters till the end of the string as the second one.  In the replacement we can use `_` in between the first (`\\1`) and second (`\\2`) capture  groups.

```
sub('(.{6})(.*)$', '\\1_\\2', v1)
#[1] "B02001_001" "B02001_002" "B23020_003" "B19057_001"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("B02001001","B02001002","B23020003","B19057001")
```